# How to allow cron to run if root password is expired in ubuntu

Tags: cron

Password expiration has been set for the root account.
After the password of the root account has expired, the cron command with root privileges is not executed.

Can I skip the authentication of pam_unix.so for cron?

```
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 CRON[3556]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 CRON[3557]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 CRON[3555]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 cron[11919]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 CRON[3554]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 cron[11919]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 CRON[3553]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 cron[11919]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
May 17 17:39:01 AIOS50 CRON[3552]: Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required
```

Comment: "After the password of the root account has expired, the cron command with root privileges is not executed." That is the whole idea of security "Can I skip the authentication of pam_unix.so for cron?" Not without removing or patching pam. You really should re-evaluate the way you approach this. I would suggest to not use password expiration but code something specific in `/etc/profile` to prevent logging in. Mind though... we don't use "root" in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, the information below guides the setting method, but ubuntu cannot be applied because the format is different.
Is there any way?

https://hotpotato.tistory.com/685